# angular 12 custom validator validate one item is selected from array

Tags: validation, angular-material, formgroups, angular-validator

HI I am doing an **Angular 12 App** using **Material**.

I have my FormGroup like this

```
form:FormGroup=new FormGroup({
    Id: new FormControl(null),
    Name: new FormControl('',Validators.required),
    Recipents: new FormControl('',[Validators.required, matchingEmailValidator()]),

    IsActive: new FormControl(true),
    ProcessorName: new FormControl('',Validators.required),
    Channel: new FormArray([],[ matchingCheckValidator()]),
  });
```

Where I have an Arrays of checkboxes loaded dinamically from database.

I want to put a **Custom Validator** to validate that at least one checkbox is selected. If not, use a

```
<mat-error>This field is mandatory</mat-error>
```

Also I have a variable called `channelList` with all my checkbox already selected.

```
 changeEventFunc( ob: MatCheckboxChange) {

    if (ob.checked) {
      this.channelList.push(ob.source.id);
    } else {
      this.channelList.forEach((element,index)=>{
        if(element== ob.source.id)
        {
         this.channelList.splice(index, 1);
        }
        }
      )}
  }
```

I had defined a function call **matchingCheckValidator** where I want to put the validation

```
    export function matchingCheckValidator(): ValidatorFn {
      return (control:AbstractControl) : ValidationErrors | null => {
        do the task
        }
      }
    }
```

Here is my HTML

```
<mat-label><strong>Channel</strong></mat-label>
          <li *ngFor="let chanel of notification.NotificationChannelLogLevels">
            <mat-checkbox id= {{chanel.NotificationLogLevel.Id}} formArrayName="Channel"
            [checked]="chanel.IsActive"
             (change)="changeEventFunc($event)">
              {{chanel.NotificationLogLevel.Name}}
            </mat-checkbox>
          </li>
```

I need to run the custom validation everytime a checkbox is selected...

Is that posible?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no other way than to use custom validator function.

```
/**
 * Form Control Validator function to check if given `array` contains `control.value`
 * - If `array` is array of objects there is option to check value by object property (`key`)
 * @param array input array of primitive values (strings, numbers) OR objects
 * @param key (optional) object property/key
 * @returns `null` (**valid**) OR `{ doesntContain: true }` (**invalid**)
 */
export function containsValueValidator(array: any[], key?: string): ValidatorFn {
  return (control: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors | null => {
    const valid = array.includes(control.value) || (key && array.includes(control.value[key]));
    const error: ValidationErrors = { doesntContain: true };

    return valid ? null : error;
  }
}
```

Then, in all the places where you want to apply this validator dynamically (if you suppose `array` can change), you have to use following functions in the right way, e.g.:

```
nameControl.clearValidators();
nameControl.addValidators([Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(30), containsValueValidator(availableNamesFromDropdown)]);
nameControl.setValue(currentName);
nameControl.updateValueAndValidity();
```

I hope this helps some people in the future

## To your specific problem

If you want to update validator on every checkbox selected, you have to do it on every `(change)` event's handler